# Can a UIImageView be partially hidden by keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios4, keyboard, uiimageview

In iOS4 iPhone when the keyboard opens, some text fields can be hidden or clipped by the keyboard.

Instead, if there is a UIImageView, this is scaled, stretched, and so on.

Can you ensure that the UIImageView remains at the same place and is only, possibly, hidden, clipped by an open keyboard (as a UITextField)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the keyboard appears is entirely up to you. If you want your image view not to move, don't move it.